# Base64 Decoding for Mac OS app using Swift

Tags: swift, macos, base64

My OAuth2 authority returns this to me:

```
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
```

After copy and pasting that string into:

https://www.base64decode.org

I get returned a nice JSON body. This one:

```
{"email":"rutger@you.co","updated_at":1523872917,"exp":1524041271,"iat":1524041151,"sub":"rutger@YOU-TECHNOLOGIES-GROUP-LIMITED","iss":"https://you-technologies-group-limited.vmwareidentity.asia/SAAS/auth","aud":["YOU_Portal"],"auth_time":1524031451,"azp":"YOU_Portal","at_hash":"FvkfxCiQMmUXXMDG-sPA7A","c_hash":"NT_stiflH-fK_IPpJ11mSQ","given_name":"Rutger","family_name":"Huijmans","email_verified":true}
```

I can't seem to Base64 Decode this in my Mac OS app though. No matter what I've tried.

For example:

```
let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: idToken)!
let decodedString = String(data: decodedData, encoding: .utf8)!
print(decodedString)
```

This crashes.

Comment: Adding 1 or 2  simple `=` at the end should fix this. I think that website does that automatically, it should have notified in my opinion.

Comment: It works! Bedankt Henk!